# C freeing check doesn't work

Tags: c, free, dynamic-memory-allocation, dangling-pointer

I have written a method to free my struct. Now I have a problem. When I call this method twice, it gives me an error. But I do check if there is something in my struct so I don't know how it is possible that it gives me the error.

My struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int num_rows;
    int num_cols;
    int** data;
} matrix;
```

My free method:

```
void free_matrix(matrix* m){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<m->num_rows;i++){
        if(m->data[i]!=NULL){
            free(m->data[i]);
        }
    }
    if(m->data!=NULL){
        free(m->data);
    }
}
```

Extra methods:

```
void fill_matrix_a(matrix* m){
    m->data[0][0] = 1;
    m->data[0][1] = 0;
    m->data[0][2] = 2;
    m->data[1][0] = 0;
    m->data[1][1] = 3;
    m->data[1][2] = 1;
}

void fill_matrix_b(matrix* m){
    m->data[0][0] = 0;
    m->data[0][1] = 3;
    m->data[1][0] = 2;
    m->data[1][1] = 1;
    m->data[2][0] = 0;
    m->data[2][1] = 4;
}

void init_matrix(matrix* m, int num_rows, int num_cols){
    int i;
    m->num_cols = num_cols;
    m->num_rows = num_rows;
    m->data = (int**) calloc(num_rows,sizeof(int*));
    if(m->data==NULL){
        printf("%s\n", "ERROR: probleem bij geheugenallocatie.");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<num_rows;i++){
        m->data[i] = (int*) calloc(num_cols,sizeof(int));
        if(m->data[i]==NULL){           /* THE PROGRAM SAYS THIS IS TRUE BUT IT ISN'T BECAUSE I ALREADY FREED THE DATA OF B!! */
            printf("%s\n", "ERROR: probleem bij geheugenallocatie.");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The method which gives me an error:

```
void ex_1_matrix_operations(){
    matrix a,b,c;

    /* init a(2,3) and fill with elements */
    init_matrix(&a,2,3);
    fill_matrix_a(&a);
    print_matrix(&a);

    /* init b (default) and fill with elements */
    init_matrix_default(&b);
    fill_matrix_b(&b);
    print_matrix(&b);
    free_matrix(&a);
    free_matrix(&b);

    /* create unity matrix */
    init_identity_matrix(&a,2);
    print_matrix(&a);
    free_matrix(&a);
    free_matrix(&b); /* THIS IS WHERE MY ERROR OCCURS*/
}
```

Comment: What does not work ? What error do you get ?

Comment: free() doesn't set the pointer to NULL, you have to do it yourself, but just guessing that's your problem...

Comment: You are freeing `matrix_b` twice.

Comment: @Michael Walz, yes I know but I check if the data is NULL so it won't actually free it if i already did.

Comment: @user3371198: yes, but in `free_matrix` you don't set `m->data[i]` to NULL. The same goes for `m->data`.

Answer (score 9):

You're calling `free_matrix` twice for `a` and twice for `b`. For `a` you allocate memory first and then free it, in that order you do these operations twice; however, for `b` you allocate then release and then without allocating again, you try to release, which leads to the crash.

Calling `free` to free the memory allocated, doesn't set the pointer pointing to it to `NULL`, this has to be done manually. Without doing this, the pointer becomes a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) i.e. a pointer pointing to some location not readable (accessible) by the process. So as to avoid this, it's not uncommon to have a helper function to free memory AND set the pointer to `NULL`.

```
void free_data(void **pp)
{
    if (pp && *pp)
    {
       free(*pp);
       *pp = NULL;
    }
}
```

Although it's perfectly valid to check if the pointer is non-null, dereferencing it is undefined behaviour (UB) from the language's viewpoint. Calling `free` would ask the C runtime library to try to do that, thereby you enter UB land as per the language specification; as for the C runtime, it'll try to access memory no longer owned by the process and thus crash as the operating system would raise an access denied error of some form e.g. Linux would call this (among others) [*Segmentation Fault*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), while Windows would say *Access Violation*.

As an aside, some argue that setting a freed pointer to `NULL` is not a good practise as it masks double-deletion bugs from getting spotted. Say you set the freed pointer to `NULL` and elsewhere you call `free` with the same pointer i.e. you would essentially call `free(NULL);`. This is a valid parameter to pass to `free` and it would do nothing, thereby never knowing letting the world know that a double-deletion just happened. Had it not been set to `NULL`, the second call to `free` would raise an access violation error when trying to free the already freed location and thereby leads to the double-deletion bug to be known.

Answer (score 2):

free() does not set a pointer to NULL. You need to do that yourself.